# Push Notification sent to controller Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm implementing push notification service. I want send a variable e.regid to AppCtrl controller in AngularJS.
Could any one help me solving this problem..?

**PushCustom.js**

```
function onNotification(e) {
    switch (e.event) {
        case 'registered':
            if (e.regid.length > 0) {
                // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                //alert("regID = " + e.regid);
                AppCtrl(e.regid);
            }
            break;
        case 'message':

            if (e.foreground) {
               var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
               var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + soundfile);
                my_media.play();
            }
            break;
        case 'error':
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('AppCtrl',
                ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http, e.regid){                
                alert(e.regid); 
                $scope.regid =  e.regid;                    
                }]);
```

Anyone got any idea on how to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use AngularJS Service, as share variable between controllers.
Make setter and getter service for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Broadcast or emit depending on your scope. And catch it in your controller. Go through : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope - broadcast, emit and $on.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> switch (e.event) {
>     case 'registered':
>         if (e.regid.length > 0) {
>
>             //******************* new line ********************//
>             angular.element(document).scope().$broadcast('GCM_PUSHER',e.regid)
>         }
>         break;
>     case 'message':
>
>         if (e.foreground) {
>            var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
>            var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + soundfile);
>             my_media.play();
>         }
>         break;
>     case 'error':
>         break;
>     default:
>         break;
> } }
> ```

**Then listen broadcast event in your controller:**

> ```
> app.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){ 
>
>     $scope.$on('GCM_PUSHER',function($event,body){
>       //*********  logic here guys *********//
>     });   
>
> }]);
> ```